# how to create two sets random numbers withou repeat, how many sets is fixed

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create 4 ships in a 5 row and 5 column board, and place a symbol for each ship. but it come out sometimes only 3 ships because of duplicates. Could anyone please teach me how to do it?

```
from random import randint
add_place = []

board = []
for rows in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5) 

for i in range(4):
    add_row = randint(0, 4)
    add_col = randint(0, 4)
    add_place.append([add_row, add_col])
    board[add_row][add_col] = "@"
for i in board:        
    print(" ".join(i))
```

Comment: You have a "sample without replacement from a 2d 5-by-5 array" problem, and there are multiple ways to handle it. Consider sampling from a 25-element 1d array (using `random.sample`) and converting those values to coordinates on a 5-by-5 board.

Comment: thank you so much, it works perfect when single list is concerned, but here is a coordinate, i would like create four random coordinate lists in a list. i used if statement, but then i how should i be sure, its four sets. then i used while loop, but come out wrong.

Comment: so i wrote the following code, it seems logical and has no syntax error, but come out sometimes 3 ships instead of 4. Could any master out there please please help me:

Comment: from random import randint
add_place = []

board = []
for rows in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5) 

while len(add_place) < 4:
    add_row = randint(0, 4)
    add_col = randint(0, 4)
    if [add_row, add_col] not in board:
        add_place.append([add_row, add_col])
        board[add_row][add_col] = "@"
    
for i in board:        
    print(" ".join(i))

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
add_place = []

board = []
for rows in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5) 

    while len(add_place) < 4:
        add_row = randint(0, 4)
        add_col = randint(0, 4)
        if [add_row, add_col] not in board:
            add_place.append([add_row, add_col])
            board[add_row][add_col] = "@"

    for i in board:        
        print(" ".join(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, it turns out i made a careless mistake. i want to check add place list, not board list. the right code is as following:

```
from random import randint
add_place = []
board = []
for rows in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5) 
while len(add_place) < 4:
    add_row = randint(0, 4)
    add_col = randint(0, 4)
    add_coord = [add_row, add_col]
    if add_coord not in add_place:
        add_place.append([add_row, add_col])
        board[add_row][add_col] = "@"                       
for i in board:        
    print(" ".join(i))
```